# Bundle producing no output with "bundle exec cap deploy deploy" command

Tags: ruby, capistrano, bundler

I'm trying to deploy a site using bundler and capistrano.

- I updated to the latest version of Ruby (I was using 1.9.3 and now using 2.3.0)
- I updated bundler to 1.10.6.

Before these updates when I ran this command "bundle exec cap production deploy" it would work, now when I run that command there is NO output whatsoever.

I haven't been able to find anything online that deals with this issue.

Any help is appreciated!
Jason

Comment: did you edit the ruby version in your deploy.rb file ?

Comment: There is no ruby version in my deploy.rb file. Should there be? And if so, how do I add that?

Comment: if you use rbenv, add  `set :rbenv_ruby, '2.3.0'` , you can find example here https://github.com/TalkingQuickly/capistrano-3-rails-template/blob/master/config/deploy.rb

Comment: @jasonaburton what do you mean no version of ruby in deploy.rb?

Comment: @AbdooDev I'm using RVM. Would it be "set :rvm_ruby, '2.3.0'"?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ Ruby version is not defined in the deploy.rb file.

Comment: have you also updated all the gems?

Comment: Yes. All the gems are updated.

Comment: @jasonaburton you need to add set :rvm_ruby_version , '2.3.0' , but first you need to have capistrano-rvm gem , https://github.com/capistrano/rvm/